# Most efficient way (with no copies) to convert the data of a Mat to another class?

Tags: c++, opencv, open3d

I'm using two libraries:

- [OpenCV 4.5.4](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)
- [Open3D (latest build)](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D)

My problem is the following:
I have existing data in a OpenCV `Mat` instance. I need to transform the data into a Open3D [`Tensor`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1core_1_1_tensor.html). Both classes let me access a pointer to the underlying data, which should be continuous and in the same format.
Can this be done, without copying the data and if so how?

Comment: yes, keep the Mat around so the data will stay allocated. AFAIK opencv has no way to "release ownership" of the memory allocation. you *can* however build a cv::Mat that refers to other memory (doesn't own it)... which could be owned by the Open3D data structure. -- your only problem would be deciding which object owns the allocation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the info. At the moment the `cv::Mat` memory is allocated  by the `cv::imread()` function (Basically I want to get image data into a Tensor. Open3D provides loading functions for `.png` and `.jpg`, but I also need `.hdr` and `.exr` files, thats where OpenCV comes in). To keep the `cv::Mat` alive, I could simply make it a property of the class, where all of this happens. Just have to figure out the timeline here (who allocates and owns what)

Comment: Yes that is correct, however (at least in my case) this is an empty Mat, since I don't know the image size beforehand.

Comment: I was mistaken. `imread` can't take a result Mat. it always allocates. so you're left with what you described.

Comment: I ended up just using `std::copy`, which is fast enough for what I need